# Query returning less rows without date between condition than the direct select

Tags: mysql

Below is my query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
  SUM(rcr.impressions),
  SUM(rcr.clicks) AS clicks,
  cv.id AS cup_version_id,
  cv.source_id as source_id,
  rcr.date AS date,
  adg.subproduct_type_id
FROM
  report_custom_records AS rcr
    JOIN report_ad_groups AS adg ON (rcr.group_id = adg.ID)
    JOIN ad_campaigns AS cmp ON (adg.campaign_id = cmp.id)
    JOIN campaign_creatives AS cre ON (rcr.creative_id = cre.id)
    JOIN campaign_versions AS cv ON (cre.version_id = cv.id)
WHERE
    cmp.business_id IN (-1,9126,102538)
  AND adg.campaign_id IN (-1,870689,870696,884963,884964,902027,907809,914889,914893,925233,930390,930391,955423,955429,1004323,1004324,1021355,1021356,1078026,1078027)
  AND cast(rcr.date as date) BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-10-31'
  AND ((adg.target_type LIKE "%Pre-Roll%"  AND adg.subproduct_type_id IN (2, 4)) OR adg.subproduct_type_id IN (12, 16 , 10 ))
  AND cv.source_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
  cup_version_id, date
```

If I use it with the date condition ( between dates ), it returns the explain output as 11644969 records processed.
But If I use it without the date condition, it returns me only 1584016 records processed.

**FYI:**
date field is having date datatype
tables are used with join but no foreign keys

Table:

```
create table report_custom_records
(
    group_id         varchar(100) default '' not null,
    creative_id        int          default 0  not null,
    tp_creative_id     varchar(20)             not null,
    date               date                    not null,
    impressions        int(8)                  not null,
    clicks             int(8)                  not null,
    cost               float(6, 2)             not null,
    tp_creative_source smallint(6)             not null comment '0 = TD, 1 = DFA',
    primary key (adgroup_id, tp_creative_id, creative_id, date)
);
```

I have below indexes on the table, does it slowing the query?

```
create index adg_id
    on report_creative_records (group_id, date);

create index group_id_2
    on report_creative_records (group_id, creative_id, date);

create index group_id_3
    on report_creative_records (group_id);

create index creative_id
    on report_creative_records (creative_id);

create index date
    on report_creative_records (date);
```

Comment: Are you reading the EXPLAIN and assuming that the number of rows it says is the number of rows you will get? Don't; use COUNT(*) instead. No query expands the number of rows it gives when more restrictive predicates are added, but plans change and row counts at various parts of the pipeline will change depending on the access strategy

Comment: @CaiusJard: Thanks for a quick answer, Yes you are right about it. I was assuming it from EXPLAIN. I have below indexes on the table, does it slowing the query?

create index adg_id
 on report_creative_records (group_id, date);

create index group_id_2
 on report_creative_records (group_id, creative_id, date);

create index group_id_3
 on report_creative_records (group_id);

create index creative_id
 on report_creative_records (creative_id);

create index date
 on report_creative_records (date);

Comment: Really can't say; if you want query performance advice you have to post up the tables, indexes, the plan, etc..